# How do I make PyQt buttons work?

Tags: python, list, button, click, pyqt5

"Create a program in PyQt that is aimed towards benefiting a local community library. The program should be able to add, edit and delete book entries to and from the inventory list.

Include one list widget, one line edit box, one label, four push buttons."

I can drag and drop all these things into PyQt5, save it as .ui, convert to .py and open in IDLE, but **how do I make the buttons do anything?**  Also, how do I get my IDLE to display this box?

[This is what the program should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E51O3.jpg)

This is the code I am left with after saving the .ui file and converting to .py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'listoper.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.6
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 450)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(260, 180, 256, 192))
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 230, 171, 91))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.Enterbookdetails = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.Enterbookdetails.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 200, 101, 16))
        self.Enterbookdetails.setObjectName("Enterbookdetails")
        self.Add = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Add.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 330, 75, 23))
        self.Add.setObjectName("Add")
        self.Delete = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Delete.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 330, 75, 23))
        self.Delete.setObjectName("Delete")
        self.Edit = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Edit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 370, 75, 23))
        self.Edit.setObjectName("Edit")
        self.Deleteall = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.Deleteall.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 370, 75, 23))
        self.Deleteall.setObjectName("Deleteall")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.Enterbookdetails.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Enter Book Details:"))
        self.Add.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Add"))
        self.Delete.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Delete"))
        self.Edit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Edit"))
        self.Deleteall.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Delete All"))
```

Apparently I am supposed to use the following code, but my buttons still don't work:

## The kilogram to pound button:

```
def btn_KtoP_clicked(self):
kilo = float(self.edt_Kilo.text())
pound = (kilo * 2.2)
self.edt_Pounds.setText(str(pound))
```

## The pound to kilogram button:

```
def btn_PtoK_clicked(self):
pound = float(self.edt_Pounds.text())
kilo = (pound/2.2)
self.edt_Kilo.setText(str(kilo))
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your above code, this should work

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from YOUR_UI_MODULE import Ui_MainWindow
class sow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent)


        self.main_ui=Ui_MainWindow()
        self.main_ui.setupUi(self)
        self.main_ui.Add.clicked.connect(self.doAdd)
        self.main_ui.Edit.clicked.connect(self.doEdit)


    def doAdd(self):
        print("do add")

    def doEdit(self):
        print("do edit")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = sow()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

checkout the examples which came with your PyQT5 installation and start from there.
mine is located here C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\PyQt5\examples

PyQT has a reference doc, mine is located here C:/Python32/Lib/site-packages/PyQt4/doc/html/classes.html

I will recommend reading this tutorial before coding further, so you know what you are doing.
http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/firstprograms/